# Find all pairs of nodes whose deletion disconnects graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, language-agnostic

Given undirected, connected graph, find all pairs of nodes (connected by an edge) whose deletion disconnects the graph.
No parallel edges and no edges connecting node to itself.

The problem seems similar to finding articulation points (or bridges) of a connected, undirected graph - yet with a twist, that we have to remove a pair of vertices connected by an edge (and all other edges connected to that pair).

This is a homework question. I've been trying to solve it, read about DFS and articulation points algorithms (that bookkeap depth and lowpoint of each node) - but none of these approaches help this particular problem. I've checked through Cormen's Intro to Algorithms, but no topic suggested itself as appropriate (granted, book does have 1500 pages).

While it's true that finding articulation point would also (most of the time) find such a pair, there are a lot of pairs that are not articulation points - consider a graph with 4-vertices,5-edges (square with a single diagonal): it has one such pair but no articulation points (nor bridges).

I'm lost. Help me, stack overflow, you are my only hope.

Answer (score 1):

Rather straightforward, maybe not the most efficient:

Let the graph be G=(V,E) with V := {v_1, ..., v_n}. For each subset V' of V let G_V' be the node induced subgraph comprising the nodes V \ V'. Let further N>_v_i := {v_j in V : {v_i,v_j} in E and j > i} be the set of all neighbors of v_i in G with index greater than i. Finally, let c(G) be the set of connected components of a graph.

Compute the pairs as follows:

```
pairs = {}
for each v in V:
    compute G_{v}
    if G_{v} is unconnected:
        for each v' in N>_v:
            # Ensures that removal of v' does not render subgraph connected
            # (Note comment by MkjG)
            if |c(G_{v})| > 2 or {v'} not in c(G_{v}):
                add {v,v'} to pairs
    else:
        for each v' in N>_v:
            compute G_{v,v'}
            if G_{v,v'} unconnected:
                add {v,v'} to pairs
```

Connectivity can be checked via DFS or BFS in O(m+n). The runtime should hence be O(n * k * (m+n)), where k is the maximum degree of G.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment the answer given by TheWildHealer, however, I believe it is wrong. As a counterexample, define two [k-cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) G_1 and G_2 with k>1. Add two additional nodes s_1 and s_2. Connect both s_1 and s_2 with all nodes in G_1 and G_2. Connect further s_1 with s_2. Clearly, removing s_1 and s_2 renders the graph unconnected. I didn't make a prove, but I suppose removing any k edges does not. 2 edges most definitely do not suffice. Hence, 2-cuts and probably k-cuts in general do not get you anywhere with this problem.

Comment: @the_anonymous There is at least a small bug in the first case. Consider simple 3-vertex, 2-edges graph: (1-2-3). Since G_(2) is unconnected, (2,3) is identified as a pair, but it isn't: removing (2,3) results in connected graph (1). Also, the first case (removing one node results in unconnected graph) is basically articulation point (with one additional constraint, that it's neighbor has a neighbor) which is O(m+n). I can't help but wonder if there's anyway to improve the second case, or at least find pairs from the first case first, in a single DFS.

Comment: You are right, I had not thought of that possibility. I edited my answer to correct that mistake. I also added a second answer with a more efficient algorithm that makes use DFS to compute articulation points, according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Update to my previous answer based on the suggestion by @MkjG to use DFS for computing articulation points.

Let the graph be G=(V,E) with V := {v_1, ..., v_n}_. For each subset V' of V let G_V' be the node induced subgraph comprising the nodes V \ V'. For G connected, we call v in V an articulation point if G_{v} is unconnected. Let N_v be the set of neighbors of v in G.

Articulation points can be computed via DFS, read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/articulation-points-or-cut-vertices-in-a-graph/) for more information on the algorithm. In short:

1. compute a DFS tree T for some root node r in V
2. r is an articulation point, iff it has more than one child in T
3. any other node v in V is an articulation point, iff it has a child v' in T that satisfies the following condition: no node in the subtree T' of T rooted at v' has a back edge to an ancestor of v

Let the result of a DFS on graph G be a function c on the nodes v in V. c(v) is a subset of N_v, it holds v' in c(v) iff both of the following conditions are met:

1. v' is a child of v in T
2. no node in the subtree T' of T rooted at v' has a back edge to an ancestor of v

Note that for the root node r of T, c(r) is the set of all children of r. Function c can be computed in time O(n+m).

Compute the separator pairs as follows:

```
# performs DFS on G for some root node r
c = DFS(G,r)
# computes articulation points of G and corresponding number of components
aps = {}
compCounts = {}
for each v in V:
    numComps = |c(v)|
    if v != r:
        ++numComps
    if numComps > 1:
        add v to aps
        compCounts[v] = numComps
# computes the set of all separator pairs containing at least on ap
S = {}
for each v in aps:
    numComps = compCounts[v]
    for each v' in N_v:
        if numComps > 2:
            # G_{v,v'} has at least two connected components
            add {v,v'} to S
        else:
            # if v' is an isolated node in G_{v}, then G_{v,v'} is connected
            if N_v' != {v}:
                add {v,v'} to S
# computes remaining separator pairs
for each v in V \ aps:
    compute G_{v}
    # performs DFS on G_{v} for some root r_v != v
    c_v = DFS(G_{v},r_v)
    # adds separator pairs for articulation points of G_{v} in N_v
    for each v' in N_v:
        numComps = |c(v')|
        if v' != r_v:
            ++numComps
        if numComps > 1:
            add{v,v'} to S
```

Runtime is in O(n * (n+m))

Comment: I've found algorithms that do that in O(V+E): https://scholar.uwindsor.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5979&context=etd You can CTRL+F it for "separation pairs". Algorithm starts in chapter 3. 

Thanks for help, though :)

Comment: This algo requires that we operate on a 2-connected tree, but I can just create 2-connected forest from a given graph based on first part of your algorithm (which is also n+m).

Comment: This link actually makes algorithm a lot clearer: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-44541-2_8.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A set of k edges disconnecting a graph is called a k-cut. You are trying to enumerate all 2-cuts of a graph.

[This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0ahUKEwiKztWN_bnbAhUHbxQKHezeDu8QFghbMAY&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.228.5887%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw3iv8yBcEeC0Y1vz_XE4CVJ) describes an efficient algorithm to enumerate all cuts of a graph. It should be possible to adapt it to find all 2-cuts of a graph.

Comment: Not quite. As far as I understand 2-cut is just a partition of a graph into two subraphs by removing set of edges. The conditions here are more strict, as edges have to be adjecent to a pair of adjecent vertices, and also more relaxed, as any k-cut will do (the only condition is the resulting graph can't be connected). I think I'm looking for all vertex separators of cardinality 2.